# Wrong elements added to object in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I’m trying to make a work schedule generator in Node. In this component, I’m trying to assemble a random schedule for a specific month, using a template and a random number generator. I’m also adding a date to the final objects.

Minimal reproducible example:

```js
var templates = [
  {
    "name": "test",
    "values": [ "val1", "val2", "val3" ],
    "date": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "values": [ "val4", "val5", "val6" ],
    "date": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "values": [ "val7", "val8", "val9" ],
    "date": ""
  }
];

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
  var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
  var days = [];
  
  while (date.getMonth() === month) {
    var day = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();
    
    days.push(day);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  
  return days;
}

const generateWorkSchedule = (month, year) => {
  var days = getDaysInMonth((month - 1), year);
  var schedule = []

  console.log("days", days);

  for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    var daySchedule = {};
    
    daySchedule = templates[getRandomInt(3)]
    daySchedule.date = days[i]
    console.log(`days[${i}]`, days[i]);
    schedule.push(daySchedule)
  }

  return schedule
}

console.log(generateWorkSchedule(12, 2021));
```

Output (dates change every run):

```js
[
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 29.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 29.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    values: [ 'val4', 'val5', 'val6' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 28.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 29.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    values: [ 'val4', 'val5', 'val6' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 28.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    values: [ 'val4', 'val5', 'val6' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 28.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 29.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    values: [ 'val4', 'val5', 'val6' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 28.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 29.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 29.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    values: [ 'val4', 'val5', 'val6' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 28.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 29.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 29.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    values: [ 'val4', 'val5', 'val6' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 28.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    values: [ 'val4', 'val5', 'val6' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 28.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    values: [ 'val4', 'val5', 'val6' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 28.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    values: [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 29.'
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    values: [ 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' ],
    date: '2021. 11. 30.'
  }
]
```

The problem is, the final objects have random dates instead of dates in order. I tried it without the random number generator, the problem still stands.

The `console.log` outputs are looking good.

So it seems to be good, but the final results have random dates. I’m ether doing something really wrong, or node or JS have some weird low level stuff I dont know about.

Comment: Can you create an actual [mre] please?

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Edited. I also snuck in the desired result, but basically I'm trying to get object with dates in order.

Comment: @DevSquid Run the snippet. `export default generateWorkSchedule` still causes an error. And the second snippet does nothing.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Run it with node in your own enviroment and call it in an index.js.
Also the second snippet is an output. I just put it in a snippet os it's more readable.

Comment: You’re overwriting the same set of objects from `templates` over and over. `daySchedule = templates[getRandomInt(3)]` does _not_ create a clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky one, for sure! I ran the code several times and I think I see what the problem is. In your `generateWorkSchedule` function, you are retrieving the template from the array and setting it to a variable. Then, your function updates *that* object (updates the actual template with `daySchedule.date = days[i]`). Each iteration through the loop in `generateWorkSchedule` resets the template's `date` to be the last day. For objects, [JavaScript uses "pass by reference"](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/explain-javascript-pass-by-reference-in-javascript) and you are not making a copy of your work schedule template. Try this function (though, I'm sure there are other ways of solving this problem, this was one way that worked for me):

```js
const generateWorkSchedule = (month, year) => {
  var days = getDaysInMonth((month - 1), year);
  var schedule = []
  for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    var template = templates[getRandomInt(3)];
    var daySchedule = { 
      name: template.name,
      values: template.values,
      date: days[i],
    }
    schedule.push(daySchedule)
  }

  return schedule
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. Yeah, I think I've heard "pass by reference" somewhere, but I never really understood it to behave like this.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, that article was really helpful to me to learn about "pass by ..."—hopefully it's helpful to you, too!